# Inquiry about determinant of $ \left(\begin{matrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{matrix}\right)$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Based off of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices, I'm trying to find the formula for $\det(M)$ when $M = \left(\begin{matrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{matrix}\right)$. It is known that $A$ and $C$ are diagonal matrices in my use case.

I don't even know where to begin proving this. Any proofs or hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Erm, no, that was a mistake. I'll edit that. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is invertible, then the factorization
$$M:=\left(\begin{array}{cc} A & B \\ B^T & C\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cc} A & 0 \\ B^T & 1\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & A^{-1}B \\ 0 & C-B^TA^{-1}B\end{array}\right)$$
implies that
$$\operatorname{det}M=\operatorname{det}A\cdot \operatorname{det}\left(C-B^TA^{-1}B\right).$$
Similarly, if $C$ is invertible, then
$$\operatorname{det}M=\operatorname{det}C\cdot \operatorname{det}\left(A-BC^{-1}B^T\right).$$
If both $A$ and $C$ are invertible, one can write the result in a symmetric form:
\begin{align*}\operatorname{det}M&=\operatorname{det}A\cdot\operatorname{det}C\cdot \operatorname{det}\left(1-A^{-1}BC^{-1}B^T\right)=\\
&=\operatorname{det}A\cdot\operatorname{det}C\cdot \operatorname{det}\left(1-C^{-1}B^TA^{-1}B\right)
\end{align*}
The first formula is preferable when the size of $A$ is much smaller than the size of $C$ and vice versa.
The diagonal form of $A,C$ does not simplify the result and its derivation.

Comment: This is correct and evident from the wiki page, IIRC. I was hoping for some simplification due to $B^T$, really. I just don't have enough exposure to linear algebra to know where to go to find that. I will accept this barring no better answers.

Comment: @Logan Sorry, but I doubt that there exists something simpler or "better" than the above half-line calculation. Another derivation that I know uses Gaussian integrals and is much more involved

Comment: I suspected as much, but I hoped someone with more experience had some insight I lacked. :) Thanks.